# Preview not updating properly in Dynamic Add / Remove file fields

Tags: javascript

I have created following piece of code. The entire code is working properly except the preview of images. The first field updates the image preview properly.

But when we add image in subsequent dynamic file fields it updates the preview of first field only.

I want to update preview of each file field with image selected of its own respectively...

Following is my code...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <center><b>Team Members</b></center>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <script type='text/javascript'>
            function preview_member(event) {
              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onload = function() {
                var output = document.getElementById('member_image');
                output.src = reader.result;
              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
            }
          </script>
          <img src="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('/profile-images/blank-image.png') ); ?>" id="member_image" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Add Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event)" style="display: none;"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_name">Member Name <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_role">Role in Project <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_email">Email address <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_facebook_id">Facebook Username <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_facebook_id[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="add-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Member</button>
    <br>
    <div id="member-fields">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //fadeout selected item and remove
    $(document).on('click', '#remove-member-fields', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).empty();
        return false;
      });
    });

    var rows = `<div class="team-member-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( site_url(' / profile - images / blank - image.png ') ); ?>" alt=""></div><div class="form-group"><label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Add Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event)" style="display: none;"></label></div></div><div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label for="member_name">Member Name <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_role">Role in Project <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_email">Email address <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_facebook_id">Facebook Username <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_facebook_id[]" placeholder=""></div></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="remove-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove Member</button><br></div></div></div>`;

    //add input
    $('#add-member-fields').click(function() {
      $(rows).fadeIn("slow").appendTo('#member-fields');
      i++;
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Please help me out with a solution... Thanks...

Comment: What `But when we add image in subsequent dynamic file fields it updates the preview of first field only.` means?

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee the preview of first field image only gets change.. I want each field to get its own image preview..

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee Perfect code Thanks... :)

Comment: Your welcome, You can accept the answer if it is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put specific id for each image tag. change these:

**1-move your `row` variable into `onclick` event**

**2-increase `i` counter after each time you add element**

```
//add input
$("#add-member-fields").click(function() {
i++;

var rows = `<div class="team-member-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( site_url(' / profile - images / blank - image.png ') ); ?>"
id="member_image${i}" alt=""></div><div class="form-group"><label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Add Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event, ${i})" style="display: none;"></label></div></div><div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label for="member_name">Member Name <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_role">Role in Project <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_email">Email address <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_facebook_id">Facebook Username <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_facebook_id[]" placeholder=""></div></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="remove-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove Member</button><br></div></div></div>`;

$(rows)
  .fadeIn("slow")
  .appendTo("#member-fields");
return false;
});
});
```

**3-change function input parameters and add index number to it**

```
function preview_member(event, inp) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log(inp);
  reader.onload = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById("member_image" + inp);
    output.src = reader.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Final code will be this

```js
var i = 0;

function preview_member(event, inp) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log(inp);
  reader.onload = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById("member_image" + inp);
    output.src = reader.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //fadeout selected item and remove
  $(document).on("click", "#remove-member-fields", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).empty();
        return false;
      });
  });

  //add input
  $("#add-member-fields").click(function() {
    i++;

    var rows = `<div class="team-member-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( site_url(' / profile - images / blank - image.png ') ); ?>"
id="member_image${i}" alt=""></div><div class="form-group"><label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Add Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event, ${i})" style="display: none;"></label></div></div><div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label for="member_name">Member Name <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_role">Role in Project <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_email">Email address <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" placeholder=""></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_facebook_id">Facebook Username <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_facebook_id[]" placeholder=""></div></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="remove-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove Member</button><br></div></div></div>`;

    $(rows)
      .fadeIn("slow")
      .appendTo("#member-fields");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <center><b>Team Members</b></center>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('/profile-images/blank-image.png') ); ?>" id="member_image0" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Add Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event, 0)" style="display: none;"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_name">Member Name <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_role">Role in Project <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_email">Email address <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="member_facebook_id">Facebook Username <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_facebook_id[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="add-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Member</button>
    <br>
    <div id="member-fields">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```